# What is the difference between the Free and + versions of the Holiday Pack?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In a recent Square Enix email i got talking about the new DLC it showed me this

[image: Holiday Pack]

Now it says that there are 2 versions of the Holiday Pack, one free and one for Season Pass Holders. one difference i notice is in the next image

[image: Moogle Chocobo Carnival]

It talks about a Carnival Ticket but 2 versions, a normal one and a + one which i assume is what is in the Season Pass version.

But how are these different? is it just this ticket? how is this ticket different in-game that would warrant someone getting a Season Pass over the free version of the Holiday Pack?

NOTE: the email came in 5 hours prior to posting this but it's the 23rd for me and the Holiday Pack DLC already appears on the Playstation Store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: [Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/final-fantasy-xv-gets-new-game-plus-next-week-1790183962)

The free version of the Holiday DLC includes the following:

> - Warrior’s Fanfare – A scroll of sheet music containing a song of jubilation that provides additional AP for earning an A+ in Offense outside of training.
> - Nixperience Band – A device that stops experience points from being tallied, preventing the party from leveling up for an added challenge.
> - Carnival Passport – An adorably adorned ticket that whisks the bearer away to a fun-filled carnival for a limited time.
> - Choco-Mog Tee (available late January) – An exclusive T-shirt featuring everyone’s favorite fluffy and feathery friends. Colorful, comfy and appropriate for any carnival-goer.

The Season Pass version of the Holiday DLC adds the following:

> - Ring of Resistance – A protective piece of jewelry that renders the entire party to be resistant to magical friendly fire.
> - Tech Turbocharger – A device for Noctis that accelerates the tech bar replenishment rate, but freezes the Armiger bar.
> - Armiger Accelerator – A device for Noctis that accelerates the Armiger bar replenishment rate, but freezes the tech bar.
> - Blitzer’s Fanfare – A scroll of sheet music containing a song of jubilation that provides additional AP for earning an A+ in Time outside of training.
> - Tactician’s Fanfare – A scroll of sheet music containing a song of jubilation that provides additional AP for earning an A+ in Finesse outside of training.
> - Key of Prosperity – A lucky charm that increases the rate at which fallen foes leave behind items of value.
> - Stamina Badge – A device that enables Noctis to sprint and hang without expending stamina.
> - Festive Ensemble (available late January) – A fancy and fun outfit perfectly suited for enjoying the festivities. The darling design puts all who see it in high spirits.
> - Holiday Pack + Exclusive Photo Frames (available late January) – Additional themes the player can add to Prompto’s photos when sharing over social media.

**EDIT**: Regarding the Carnival Passport specifically, the [DLC description on the Playstation Store](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-ca/games/addons/ffxv-holiday-pack-(free-version)/cid=UP0082-CUSA01633_00-HOLIDAYFREE00001) states "The Carnival Passport is functionally identical to the paid version."

Comment: While the title of the question may be asking about the Holiday Passes, part of the OP's question is asking about the difference between the Carnival Pass and Carnival Pass+. This is not mentioned in the article

Comment: Does the nixperience band stop you from earning the XP or does it just mean once you sleep it doesn't level you up? It sounds like it could be quite useful to allow me to camp more without wasting XP bonuses! :)

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5jmtnf/question_to_australian_players_that_have_already/), it just prevents XP from being tallied when you rest. So you can camp just for the food buffs, or finish a story chapter, and still save up all your experience for an expensive hotel multiplier.